# What happens when I call bind() multiple times on a single socket

Tags: sockets, unix, bind

`bind()` will assign a local address to a socket. What happens when I call the `bind()` function multiple times on the same socket with different addresses (possibly with different families)?

What I want to be able to do is to bind a single socket with a local IPv4 and a local IPv6 (assigned the same local hostname in `/etc/hosts`). Can this actually work?

Will the second call to `bind()` fail? Will it replace the first bound address with the second one? Will it actually bind the socket to multiple addresses, like when binding with `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I call the `bind()` function multiple times on the same socket with different addresses (possibly with different families)?

Subsequent calls will fail with an `EINVAL` error, per the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html):

> `EINVAL`
> The socket is already bound to an address.

Also, you can't `bind()` a socket to an address family that is different than the family specified to `socket()`:

> `EINVAL`
> `addrlen` is wrong, or `addr` is not a valid address for this socket's domain.

Which means you can't create an IPv4 (`AF_INET`) socket and `bind()` it to an IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) address, and vice versa.

> What I want to be able to do is to bind a single socket with a local IPv4 and a local IPv6 (assigned the same local hostname in `/etc/hosts`). Can this actually work?

No. The only way to have a socket bound to both IPv4 and IPv6 is to create an IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) socket and disable its `IPV6_V6ONLY` option before `bind()`'ing it to address `::0` only. This is used to create a dual-stack listening socket that can accept incoming traffic from both IPv4 and IPv6 peers on all local interfaces.

If you want to `bind()` to specific addresses, you have to create a separate socket for each address.

> Will the second call to `bind()` fail?

Yes.

> Will it replace the first bound address with the second one?

No.

> Will it actually bind the socket to multiple addresses, like when binding with 0.0.0.0 ?

No.